# Rails 5 Carrierwave Uploader undefined method `to_sym' for [:photo_one, :photo_two, :photo_three]:Array Did you mean? to_s to_yaml to_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

My model has three columns I am using for image and document uploads.  I am using `Rails 5.1.4` and `Carrierwave 1.0`. I don't want a single column that accepts multiple uploads as an array so I decided to just have three individual upload options and am trying to use the same uploader.

I keep getting a `undefined method`to_sym' for [:photo_one, :photo_two, :photo_three]:Array Did you mean? to_s to_yaml to_set` error and can't seem to figure it out after hours of searching. I do have an sense my uploader is wrong, but my current knowledge level is making it hard to tell for sure.

**models/plaqueorder.rb**

```
class Plaqueorder < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader [:photo_one, :photo_two, :photo_three], DocumentUploader
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**uploaders/document_uploader.rb**

```
class DocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [100, 50]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf)
  end
end
```

Comment: can you even use an array there? the docs do it with 3 calls to mount_uploader... http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave%2FMount%3Amount_uploader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define uploader for each field separately. If you will go through the [mount_uploader sources](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L134) you will see that array of colums not supported